# How can i get Details from Database and Display to my Customized Page

Tags: magento-1.9, database, page, request

I need to get d`etails from database`, `**Actually am installed extension form builder**`, i get details from that, and get that details from database and `display into my customized page`, like name, user image, age, d-o-b.

> **my page like**,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA1k7.png

> **My code part**,

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
<style type-"text/css">
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.module {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f06d06;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid blue;  
  margin: 20px;
}
.module:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row1">
<div class= "col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="module">    
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="module"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<div class="module">  
</div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<div class="module"> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module">
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module">    
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module"> 
</div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module"> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row3">
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module">    
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module">  
</div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row3">
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module">    
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module">  
</div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row3">
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module">    
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
    <div class="module"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module">  
</div>
</div>
<div class= "col-md-3">
<div class="module">
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> **My db details** :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M15wf.png

Answer (score 2):

You can get deatail of particular customer by code-

`if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
    print_r($customerData->getData());
}`

Comment: Not working.....

Comment: i get error like : Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /home/xyz/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 463

Answer (score 0):

you can get all customer data by following code

```
$collection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $customer){
      print_r($customer->getData);
}
```

In above code you will get customer data set in your HTML By your own.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45032/create-a-reminder-for-incomplete-orders-in-admin

Comment: not working.....

Comment: i get error like : Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /home/xyz/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 463